# Blazor navigate to same URL but different id

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-routing

I have problem when navigating from

`"/vehicle-definitions/1/can-networks/5"`
to

`"/vehicle-definitions/1/can-networks/6"`

Basically, what happens is nothing. I would like and excepted behaviour is to load this new page with id 6, load from database, and show new item on page. But it seems, Blazor thinks this is same page (what basically it is). I tried with `<a href` , and setting lik using `<NavLink` but without success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to override the OnParametersSetAsync() methode and reload data from Database.

First change you route like below

`/vehicle-definitions/1/can-networks/{id}`

Then you set a property with [ParameterAttribute]

```
[Parameter] 
public string Id{ get; set; }
```

And now you can override the OnParametersSetAsync methode and reload new data with changed parameter

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    LoadData(Id);
}
```

Comment: Probably it will load from database twice, in OnParametersSetAsync and on OnIntiialiedAsync. Maybe I could put logic only inside OnParametersSetAsync probably, but what I did is to check:  if (CANNetwork.Id != id)
            {
                CANNetwork = await CANNetworkService!.GetById(int.Parse(Id));
            }

Comment: maybe you can using an other methode for this  
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
        {
            base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        }